# Exporting Excel file to the browser - ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, request

Im trying to export an excel document created from a data table to the browser/client. This works fine in an aspx code behind file, but when I have moved the method to a .cs file using MVC the method does not generate the excel file in the browser downloads bar, the response is returned as text and encoded characters in the request response, below is the code in the controller that isn't generating the file (the code saves the file to the hard disc firsts, which works correctly just doesn't send to the browser)

```
protected void ExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fromdate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateFrom);
    var todate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTo);
    var type = ddlTransactionType.SelectedValue;
    var transstatus = P2UFramework.Payment.BrainTree.GetTransactionStatus(type);

    var  transdetails = P2UFramework.Payment.BrainTree.Transactions_ByDate(transstatus, fromdate, todate.AddDays(1));

    //var dt = P2UFramework.Utility.Conversion.ListToDataTable.ToDataTable(transdetails);

    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Date");
    dt.Columns.Add("TransactionId");
    dt.Columns.Add("PatientId");
    dt.Columns.Add("PatientDetails");
    dt.Columns.Add("Email");
    dt.Columns.Add("RxOrderNo");
    dt.Columns.Add("PODOrderNo");
    dt.Columns.Add("OTCOrderNo");
    dt.Columns.Add("BrainTreeTransactionId");
    dt.Columns.Add("Amount");
    dt.Columns.Add("TransactionStatus");


    foreach (var item in transdetails)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(item.TransactionDate,  item.P2UTransactionId, item.CustomerId, item.CustomerName, item.Email, item.PrescriptionOrderID,
            item.PodOrderID, item.OtcOrderID, item.BrainTreeTransactionId, item.Amount, item.Status);
    }

    // Export to excel
    string outputFile = KwibooCommon.DataExtract.Write(dt, Server.MapPath("~/_Assets/"), KwibooCommon.DataExtract.Format.Excel);

    try
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + outputFile.Split('\\').Last());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(outputFile);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            File.Delete(outputFile);
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rob,

You're going to want to put some layers between the endpoint and ultimately reading the excel file for multiple reasons.

First, excel files by nature are extremely volatile, and not meant to be concrete data sources like SQL or even Access.

Second, you're combining a series of concerns into a single method that belong in multiple classes.  Take it from experience that this is going to be a nightmare for you to maintain in the future.  Especially if you're a VBA guru, that excel file is macro enabled, and you're going to have to maintain it moving forward.

Let's assume you have to live off of the excel file.  Read it into access at the very least.  SQL server express is free and can handle .csv imports easily out of the box.  The server connection wizard in VS can handle .mdb files if need be.  Import the data, have a plan and an automated solution to maintain it.  Ideally, have a service that reads the csv from the excel file on a regular basis into SQL.

I've been in the situation of having to develop solutions with nothing but office.  It's not fun, but there are ways to make it better.

Have a controller class that provides an endpoint and nothing else.  Have a service layer that handles business logic, and have a repository layer that does nothing but read from your data source.  I'd recommend it not be an .mdb file but if it is, VS can handle it.

I hope I've given you a brief overview of how to handle the situation.  Please ask if you have any specific questions.  I've been there, I'm happy to help.